# Control spacing around table caption

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, captions

I want to put several tables in the same table float like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Internal exon scores}\label{tab:internal}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
Ranking&Exon Coverage&Splice Site Support\\
\hline
E1&Complete coverage by a single transcript&Both splice sites\\
E2&Complete coverage by more than a single transcript&Both splice sites\\
E3&Partial coverage&Both splice sites\\
E4&Partial coverage&One splice site\\
E5&Complete or partial coverage&No splice sites\\
E6&No coverage&No splice sites\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{External exon scores}\label{tab:external}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
Ranking&Exon Coverage&Internal Splice Site Coverage\\
\hline
X1&Complete coverage by one or more transcripts&Splice site covered\\
X2&Exon coverage >= 80\%&Splice site covered\\
X3&Exon coverage < 80\%&Splice site covered\\
X4&Exon coverage < 80\%&Splice site not covered\\
X5&No coverage&Splice site not covered\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I build the document, table 2's caption is closer to the bottom of table 1, which makes things confusing. `hspace{}` doesn't seem to work in the table environment. I've worked out that the `subfloat` package appears to be causing the spacing behaviour of the captions. Is there anything else that I can do to introduce a blank horizontal break to space out the captions?

Comment: It looks fine with the `article` document class. Perhaps you could turn your code into a complete compilable file, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the behaviour?

Comment: Yup, you're right. I probably should have stripped it down to the basics before asking. I found that the problem was caused by using the subfloat package, which I require for a couple of graph floats in my document. I updated the example to a MWE that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Simply use `\vspace` between the `tabular` environements, or something like `\medskip` or `\bigskip`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The spacing is caused by the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, which is loaded by `subfig`. You can adjust the two parameters `aboveskip` and `belowskip` provided by `caption` using something like `\captionsetup{belowskip=12pt,aboveskip=4pt}` in your preamble. Note that `below` and `above` have the meaning as it would make sense for figure captions below a figure: `aboveskip` is the space between the content and the caption (which would be *above* the caption for a figure caption that's set underneath the figure, but *below* it for a table caption that's set above the table), `belowskip` is the space between the caption and the surrounding text.

Here's your example with the `aboveskip` and `belowskip` adjusted:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup{belowskip=12pt,aboveskip=4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Internal exon scores}\label{tab:internal}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
Ranking&Exon Coverage&Splice Site Support\\
\hline
E1&Complete coverage by a single transcript&Both splice sites\\
E2&Complete coverage by more than a single transcript&Both splice sites\\
E3&Partial coverage&Both splice sites\\
E4&Partial coverage&One splice site\\
E5&Complete or partial coverage&No splice sites\\
E6&No coverage&No splice sites\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{External exon scores}\label{tab:external}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
Ranking&Exon Coverage&Internal Splice Site Coverage\\
\hline
X1&Complete coverage by one or more transcripts&Splice site covered\\
X2&Exon coverage >= 80\%&Splice site covered\\
X3&Exon coverage < 80\%&Splice site covered\\
X4&Exon coverage < 80\%&Splice site not covered\\
X5&No coverage&Splice site not covered\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use `\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}`, there is still space below captions. Is there some other space that is included there too?

Answer (score 17):

Since you use `subfig`, you can adjust this by `\captionsetup` of the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, for example:

```
\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=0pt}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=10pt}
```

With these adjustments, you will get this output:

[image: tables with captions]

Answer (score 6):

without loading another package use

```
\usepackage{subfig}
 \let\belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
```