# Caption of Table "floating" above the table

Tags: tables, formatting, captions

I have the following code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin {document}
 \begin {table} [ht]
 \caption*{\bf{Table 6: Pattern of Share Ownership, 2011}}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{l r}
 \toprule
 \bf{Ownership Category} & \bf{2011}\\
 \midrule
  Foreign Ownership  & 28.99\% \\
  PIC & 6.05\% \\
  Official Pension Funds & 8.43\% \\
  Private Pension Funds & 5.47\% \\
  Long Term Insurers & 11.62\% \\
  Corporate Ownership & 22.30\% \\
  Private Direct Ownership & 17.14\% \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

which produces the following table:

[image: Table 6]

Is it possible to get the caption closer to the table? Another question - is it possible for the caption to be "wrapped" around the table?

Comment: For spacing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/control-spacing-around-table-caption,for wrapping, for sidecaption http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure

Comment: Since you are using the `caption` package anyway: Are you aware of the option `font=bf`?

Comment: A sidenote about `\bf`: Don't use it. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516) You're also using it wrong. Like `\bfseries` it is not a macro that takes an argument, it is a switch influencing the following text. So in general it should be `{\bfseries text}`, not `\bfseries{text}`.